# Coffee Soluability/Concentration

Tags: food-science

I need to know: 5 pounds ground coffee soaked in 3.5 gallons of water for 18 hours, unheated. Resulting coffee liquid extracted is x. 
How do I cut in half the water amount but still get the same amount of extracted coffee soluables into 1.75 gallons of water as would be in original 3.5 gallons?Can't allow reducing water amount by heat evaporation.
Thanks in advance,
AJR

Comment: Are you open to heating the 1.75 gallons?

Comment: Before or after the ground coffee is added?

Comment: I will take that as a no.  You don't want  to reduce and you want the same extract from half the water.

Comment: That is correct, sir.

Comment: **Rotovap:** https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotary_evaporator or **Lyophilizer:** https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Freeze-drying. Warm air vortex spray dryers are not usually suitable for the small scale operation you're considering. As you seem to know, boiling at 100°C will do awful things to your product.

Answer (score 1):

If this what you are looking for?  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coffee_extraction

There are a couple of graphs in there to help you get your ratio right (and I assume you will need to experiment on your side).

IMO, heating the coffee solution to evaporate the water will result in the degradation of the coffee; maybe render it overly bitter.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot really solve that problem with any accuracy. The amount x will vary a lot from coffee batch to coffee batch and also with grind size. The amount  extracted at a different concentration will also vary, but the connection is not linear, and extremely hard to calculate.